# Manual archive in Outlook 2010 does not work

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I try to manually archive folders in Outlook 2010 but it does not move items ( e-mails ) to archive pst file ?

Any asssiatance or idea is kindly appreciated.

Comment: Are they older than the period that you've specified for archiving? For emails if you change something about the email, like marking it as read, or deleting an attachment, the date you did that is used for working out whether to archive it, not the date it was sent.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually archive and backup an item, click on the File tab, Cleanup Tools, then Archive.

Check this out it worked for me...
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17877/how-to-manage-autoarchive-in-outlook-2010/

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, its hard to diagnose.  Is this a work (at your office) based Outlook installation?  One possibility is that your Exchange administrators have disabled the use of PSTs.